# android scroll view is giving me problems

Tags: android, scrollview

I have created an android quiz app which has a ScrollView. The problem is when you scroll down it goes back up automatically so users cannot choose the answer at the bottom. How do I fix this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/relatively"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/add"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="292dp"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.20">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.90"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout11"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.20"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/score"
                        android:layout_width="160dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Maraga : 0"
                        android:textColor="#bc42f4"
                        android:textSize="25.0sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/timers"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="00:00:49"
                        android:textColor="#ab0afb"
                        android:textSize="25.0sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textIsSelectable="true" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout12"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".8"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="1" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.40" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtQuestion"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="15*2*1-1"
                        android:textColor="#fd0213"
                        android:textSize="35.0sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="295dp"
                    android:layout_height="381dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="1"
                    android:gravity="fill_horizontal|start|end|center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:background="#09bcf8"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="30"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="25.0sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:background="#2cf309"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="29"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="25.0sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:background="#7f0af4"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="32"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="25.0sp" />

                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"

        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:transitionGroup="false">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i think you write wrong properties.

Comment: can you please show what exactly want to do. first thing is that add fillViewport=true in scrollview

Comment: change scrollView height to `wrap_content`.!!

Comment: @jankigadhiya when i say wrap_content on the scroll view the ads do not show,

Comment: @Vishal Halani i tried your solution it does not make any difference

Comment: Try my answer below @JohnsonMizzyDubula

Comment: @JohnsonMizzyDubula i  have update code now check.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:  android:layout_weight="0.20"
in your Scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code i was changed so many things in your code**

You taken so many  unnecessary layouts. make sure next time you create view with as less layout possible. because its make load on graphics.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
         >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.80"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/score"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Maraga : 0"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:textColor="#bc42f4"
                    android:textSize="25.0sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/timers"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="00:00:49"
                    android:textColor="#ab0afb"
                    android:textSize="25.0sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textIsSelectable="true" />
            </LinearLayout>


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtQuestion"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="15*2*1-1"
                    android:textColor="#fd0213"
                    android:textSize="35.0sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:background="#09bcf8"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="30"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="25.0sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:background="#2cf309"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="29"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="25.0sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:background="#7f0af4"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="32"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="25.0sp" />


        </LinearLayout>
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
            android:layout_weight="0.20"
            android:transitionGroup="false">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```